# read from remote server and write to remote server continiously

Tags: java, tcp

I want my clients to continuously read/write to a log file at a remote server.
The way I am doing it is by passing the output of tail -f /root/log.txt from my remote server to my clients.

There are 2 problems I faced

- My Server is executing the command but my client is not receiving the output.
- Only one client can connect to the server even though I used threading

Client.java

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Client
{
  Socket sock;
  String server = "XXX.XXX.XX.XX";
  int port = 5550;
  String filename = "/root/log.txt";
  String command = "tail -f "+filename+"\n";

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    new Client();
  }

  public Client()
  {
    openSocket();
    try
    {
      // write to socket
      BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(sock.getOutputStream()));
      wr.write(command);
      wr.flush();

      // read from socket
      BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
      String str;
      while ((str = rd.readLine()) != null)
      {
        System.out.println(str);
      }
      rd.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      System.err.println(e);
    }
  }

  private void openSocket()
  {
    // open a socket and connect with a timeout limit
    try
    {
      InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(server);
      SocketAddress sockaddr = new InetSocketAddress(addr, port);
      sock = new Socket();

      // this method will block for the defined number of milliseconds
      int timeout = 2000;
      sock.connect(sockaddr, timeout);
    } 
    catch (UnknownHostException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SocketTimeoutException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Server.java

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Server  {
    private int portNo = 0;
    private Socket socket = null;

    public Server(int portNo) {
        this.portNo = portNo;
        Thread t = new Thread(new acceptClient());
        t.start();
    }

    class acceptClient implements Runnable {
        public void run() {
            //while(true) {
                try {
                    ServerSocket sSocket = new ServerSocket(portNo);
                    socket = sSocket.accept();
                    System.out.println("A client has connected!");
                    BufferedWriter wr = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));

                    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
                    System.out.println(rd.readLine());
                    rd.close();
                    Process p = null;

                    p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tail -f /root/log.txt");
                    BufferedReader rd2 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
                    String s = null;
                    while ((s = rd2.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(s);
                        wr.write(s);
                    }
                    rd2.close();
                    wr.close();
                    /*try {
                            p.waitFor();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }*/

//                  /sSocket.close();
                } catch(IOException exception) {
                    System.out.println("Error: " + exception);
                }
            //}
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int portNo = 5550;
        new Server(portNo);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My Server is executing the command but my client is not receiving the output.

That's because, your command `tail -f` is a never ending command (if I am not wrong).

- Hence `rd2.readLine()` will never return `null` in `Server.java`.
- Which means your while loop will never exit.
- Which means, `wr.write(s)` will keep writing to the stream, but doesn't get a
  chance to `flush()` or `close()` it.
- Hence, the output doesn't reach
  the client.

**To Fix:** Just add `flush()` below your `write()`.

```
wr.write(s);
wr.flush();
// While loop close.
```

> Only one client can connect to the server even though I used threading

That's because, you are accepting connection only once in `Server.java`.

Just creating a new thread will not accept many connections. **You need to accept it many times in a loop.**

I would suggest you to `sSocket.accept()` and then create a separate thread for each accepted connection in a loop.

Comment: There should be some flushed output if the writer's buffer becomes full. A test with a high data volume on the tailed file should show this. Probably was never tried.

Comment: @laune, true. It should ve been flushed if lots of data came in.